# Find the shape parameter for gamma CDF with other parameters known

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, numerics

Is there a reasonably computationally efficient way to find an approximation of the shape parameter (which will always be positive, but *not* limited to integers) for a gamma CDF (scale = 1) where the other paramters are known, using the `R` programming language or associated librares?

mathematically, solve or approximate $k$ when $x$ and $F(x;k)$ are known

$$
{F(x;k)=\int _{0}^{x}f(u;k)\,du={\frac {\gamma \left(k,x\right)}{\Gamma (k)}}}
$$

where ${\Gamma (k)}$ is the gamma function and ${\displaystyle \gamma \left(k,x\right)}$ is the lower incomplete gamma function

In the book [Statistical Methods for Hospital Monitoring with R](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Statistical+Methods+for+Hospital+Monitoring+with+R-p-9781118596302), the authors create a "special cause variation" control limit based on this approximation. The example code however, uses a method where they increment the value of $k$ up by increments of 1 and then down by increments of 0.01 until an acceptable approximation is found. Computationally, I can improve this marginally with a bisection algorithm like so:

```
bisectSearch <- function(delegate, target,  lower,  upper, tolerance=0.000005, max.iterations=32L){
  for(i in 1L:max.iterations){
    half <- (lower + upper)/2
    val <- delegate(half)
    if (is.na(val)) {
      warning("NA returned - aborting")
      return(NA)
    }
    if ((abs(val - target) < tolerance)){
      return(half)
    }
    else if (val < target) {
      lower <- half
    } else {
      upper <- half
    }
  }
  warning("iteration limit exceeded\n")
  return(NA)
}
# an example input for the pgamma function
q <- 2.3
# bisection search algorithm assumes monotonically increasing function
# for a monotonically decreasing function it works if we multiply the return value and target by -1
bisectSearch(function(x){ return(-pgamma(q, x, 1)) }, target = -0.02275, lower = q, upper = 50)
# returns 6.247314
# to double check:
pgamma(q, 6.247314, 1)
# returns 0.02275199
```

Can you please help me figure out a more computationally efficient method than the `R` code above.

#### Edit

@kjetilbhalvorsen made the great suggestion in the comments to use the function `uniroot` (of which I was unaware, so many thanks)

```
uniroot(function(x) { 0.02275 - pgamma(q, x, 1) }, lower = q, 
         upper = 50, tol = 0.000005)
```

Which reduces 17 iterations (bisect search) down to 11, and some of the looping will be done in Fortran, so there will be a micro optimization here. I could potentially micro optimize further by defining the root finding function  in RCPP.

However we are still using wide limits (plucked out of thin air) to then create an approximation by applying the `pgamma` function many times. I assume the `pgamma` function is a somewhat computationally expensive approximation.

Comment: Did you try `uniroot`?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - thank you for this - I was not aware of this and have added an edit to the question above